# MPI Derived data type for a struct with flexible size

Tags: c++, mpi, memory-alignment

I am trying to send/recv in C++ a data structure that looks like this:

```c
/* PSEUDOCODE */
const int N = getN(); // not available at compile time
const int M = getM();
struct package{
    int    foo;
    double bar;
    /* I know array members do not work this way,
       this is pseudocode. */
    int    flop[N];
    double blep[M];
};
```

Since `M` and `N` are constant during runtime, I can do `MPI_Type_create_struct()` and the new datatype woule be good throughout.

My question is how to implement the data structure as described above.

`std::vector<>` won't work because it's not serial.

Flexible array members like `[]` or `[0]` are undefined behavior in c++, and it does not work for the two of `M` and `N`.

So instead I have to use `malloc()` :

```c
class Package {
public:
  // in buffer[]: bar, blep[], foo, flop[]
  // in that order and one directly follows another.
  Package():
    buffer((double*) malloc((M + 1) * sizeof(double) + 
                            (N + 1) * sizeof(int))),
    bar(buffer), blep(buffer + 1),
    foo((int*) (blep + M)),
    flop(foo + 1) {}
  ~Package(){
    free(buffer);
  }

  // construct / free the derived datatype
  static void initialize(unsigned inN, unsigned inM) {
    N = inN;
    M = inM;
    MPI_Aint offsets[2] = {0, (int)(sizeof(double)) * (M + 1)};
    int      blocks[2]  = {M + 1, N + 1};
    MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT};
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blocks, offsets, types, &packageType);
    MPI_Type_commit(&packageType);
  }
  static void finalize() {
    MPI_Type_free(&packageType);
  }

  int send(int rank, int tag) {
    return MPI_Send(buffer, 1, packageType, 
                    rank, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  int recv(int rank, int tag) {
    return MPI_Recv(buffer, 1, packageType, 
                    rank, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                    MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
private:
  double * buffer;

  static int M;
  static int N;
  static MPI_Datatype packageType;
public:
  // interface variables
  double * const bar;
  double * const blep;
  int    * const foo;
  int    * const flop;
};

int Package::N = 0;
int Package::M = 0;
MPI_Datatype Package::packageType = MPI_CHAR;
```

I tested the above code and it seems to work properly, but I am not sure if I am doing something that is actually undefined behavior. Specifically:

1. Is it ok to use `sizeof()` for `MPI_Type_create_struct()`? Some examples I find use `MPI_Type_get_extent()`, and I have no idea what is the difference.
2. I am not sure if it is a good idea to store the new datatype in a `static` member. The examples I found instead have it passed around as an argument. Is there any specific reason to do that?
3. I am also confused if this method is portable. I **hope** that it should be as portable as `struct` based methods, but perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: @Evg What do you mean by `std::vector` is not serial? `std::vector` essentially is a fancy interface for a standard array... It just provides some functions to make your life easier... Please have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data (it provides access to the underlying array)

Comment: @Evg You should only use the `static` keyword for classes where internal data has the same size for all objects. It basically shares this setting between all instances of that class, saving you some bytes. HOWEVER, if you want different objects with differently sized data structures, this is wrong. EDIT: That seems to be what you want, so `static` is right for your case.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to have 2 separate dynamic arrays (vectors) of `int`s and `double`s and send them in separate messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am also confused if this method is portable. I hope that it should be as portable as struct based methods, but perhaps I am missing something?

1. Suppose that instead of `double` and `int` you have some types `A` and `B`. Then it can happen that an object of type `B`, for which you allocate space *right after* `A`s, gets misaligned. On some architectures trying to access such an object (e.g., `int` at (4N + 2)-bytes boundary) will cause a *Bus error*. So in the general case you have to ensure correct padding before the first `B` object. When you use `struct` a compiler does it for you.

2. The way you access `buffer` is UB. Essentially you're doing this:

```cpp
double* buffer = reinterpret_cast<double*>(malloc(...));
double* bar = buffer;
int* foo = reinterpret_cast<int*>(buffer + 1);

do_something(buffer);
double bar_value = *bar; // This is UB
int foo_value = *foo;    // This is UB, too
```

The problem here is that there are no objects of type `double` and `int` at `*bar` and `*foo`. You can create them using placement `new`:

```
char* buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(malloc(...));
double* bar = new(buffer) double;
int* foo = new(buffer + sizeof(double)) int;
```

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450444/object-access-using-reinterpret-cast-for-struct-double-int-like-object).

For arrays you can use `std::uninitialized_default_construct` that constructs objects in the given range.

> I am not sure if it is a good idea to store the new datatype in a static member. The examples I found instead have it passed around as an argument. Is there any specific reason to do that?

If `N` and `M` are static, then it seems fine to make `packageType` also static. If you have only one type of `Package` with fixed `N` and `M`, you probably would want to avoid calling `MPI_Type_create_struct` each time you construct a `Package` to create essentially the same MPI data type.

But this design doesn't look good: one should call `initialize()` before first construction. Probably you can make a factory that would first create MPI data type and then would construct `Package` upon user request with something like `Package make_package()`. Then each factory could have its own non-static `N` and `M`.

Comment: I am a little confused by your second point regarding using `char *` for `buffer`. Do you mean that casting `char *` into `int *`/`double *` is fine, while casting `double *` into `int *` is UB?

Comment: @YifanLai, no. Casting is fine, but dereferencing is not if two pointers point to the same memory location. This is not the case here, but it is still UB due to another reason. I will correct my answer.